# Where smb client password saved?

Tags: samba, password

So I forgot my other PC's windows password (I haven't used it for months), and I believe I've saved it on either nemo (or maybe nautilus or thunar) when both PC connected thru `smb://10.x.x.x`.

Where does ubuntu/nemo save password of my windows PC that previously saved?

[image: nemo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so it wasn't saved on smbclient, but in `gnome-keyring`, I can see the password (and any other passwords using `seahorse`)